# authentication server microservice, should I use different services for different user functionalities

Tags: rest, authentication, microservices, oauth2-server

I have an authentication server using oauth2.

I use it for :

1. Authentication from the other services, subscription, change and retrieve password etc.
2. As resource server to store and retrieve more users and groups informations. I have a ManyToMany relationship between users and groups.

Should I seperate the second part of functionalities of this app on another standalone service that will work as resource server only. And only keep the authentication part on the authorization server?

That way I could horizontally scale these two services separately.

Comment: There are some reasons to keep everything in one place. There are many reasons to have separate services. Totally separate API can be reason. Different deployment cycle can be another reason. Different support level yet another reason. I would say there is no single answer to your question.

Comment: Ok so it depends on a lot of aspects but there is more reason to separate than to keep them in the same service if I understand well. I will think about that. For now it is a personnal project and I work alone on it but it could change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the better idea would be to have the configuration as a separate standalone service running on cloud. With configuration server as a separate service you can add all the authorization and other sort of details like DB details, API details, messaging queue configuration etc, and get connected to N number of services.

Comment: hi, here I'm not talking about separate configuration server. I already have a spring cloud config server running alone and fetching configuration for the other services from a git repository. I'm thinking about separating the authentication features from other user features.

Comment: Yes, in order to achieve scalibility we should prefer having an additional authorization server as a service

Comment: Actually here the authorization server is already a standalone service, so the database tied to it contains the users informations (credentials) (username, email, password), the basics users informations for authentication, also the tables used by oauth2 for the JDBC implmentation. Then I added other user fonctionnalities into that service like the abilty for users to create and manage user groups,  subscribe to a group etc. That is the part I'm thinking to separate into another standalone service.